# Java how do i parse this?

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, filereader

I have a file that reads as follows:

```
J1  0   90  "7,27,73,86"
J2  1   39  "12"
J3  2   195 "11,31,73,94,120,134,183"
```

I am storing the fourth column of numbers as a string

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner( new File( "projectData.txt" ) );

      while ( input.hasNext() )
      {
        job =  input.next();//
        arrival = input.nextInt();//
        cpu = input.nextInt();
        fault = input.next();   

        jobs[i] = new MyJobs( job, arrival, cpu, fault );//stores four local variables in array
        i++;//increments I
```

How do I parse the strings to store them as integers so that I may compare them to my cpu values later?

Comment: which version of Java are you using?

Comment: Try to split the string by fault.split(","), and the you can use Integer.parseInteger(fault[1]); to parse as a string.

Answer (score 3):

Basic approach would be to remove the double quotes using `String.substring()` then `String.split()` by the comma into a `String[]`.  From here you know how big an `int[]` needs to be, so just iterate through the `String[]` and convert each element to an `int`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String fault = "\"11,31,73,94,120,134,183\"";
    String[] pieces = fault.substring(1, fault.length() - 1).split(",");

    int[] faultNumbers = new int[pieces.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < faultNumbers.length; i++) {
        faultNumbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(pieces[i]);
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(faultNumbers));
}
```

Results:

```
[11, 31, 73, 94, 120, 134, 183]
```

### Java 8 Streams

To build off of @alfasin answer with streams the basic approach can be shortened.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String fault = "\"11,31,73,94,120,134,183\"";
    String[] pieces = fault.substring(1, fault.length() - 1).split(",");

    // This does the job of the for loop in the basic approach
    int[] faultNumbers = Arrays.stream(pieces)
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
            .toArray();

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(faultNumbers));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8:

```
String s = "11,31,73,94,120,134,183";
Object [] res =
                Stream.of(s.split(","))
                    .map(Integer::valueOf)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())                                
                    .toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res)); // [11, 31, 73, 94, 120, 134, 183]
```

This can probably implemented in a more elegant way. I'm still playing with Java 8... :)

Pay attention that the result is an array of Objects, not of Integers, but it's easy to "convert" each object to integer using casting.

The same result can also be achieved by the old ways of splitting by comma and converting each substring to integer using [`Integer.valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html):

```
String s = "11,31,73,94,120,134,183";
String[] sArray = s.split(",");
Integer[] res = new Integer[sArray.length];
for (int i=0; i < sArray.length; i++) {
    res[i] = Integer.valueOf(sArray[i]);
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res)); // [11, 31, 73, 94, 120, 134, 183]
```